# How do I find the average and the top grade in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, average

In this piece of code I would like to find out the top mark that a student has got, and also the average of all the marks. The marks are put into an ArrayList by user input. I have half done the double but do not know how to finish it, and I would like to know how to find the top mark.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Course
{
    private ArrayList<Student> people = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public void add( Student s )
    {
        people.add( s );
    }
    //Return the number of students who passed (mark>= 40)
    public int pass()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for ( int i=0; i < people.size(); i++ )

        {
            int mark = people.get(i).getMark();
            if(mark < 40){
                count = count +1;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public int fail()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for ( int i=0; i < people.size(); i++ )

        {
            int mark = people.get(i).getMark();
            if(mark < 40){
                count = count +1;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

   public String top()
   {

   }

    public double average()
    {
        int sum=0;

        for (int i=0; i < people.size(); i++ )
        {
            double average = sum / (double) i;
        }

        return sum;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please be precise. Just post the code that you are having an issue with and what you've tried. Can you `pseudocode` this and figure out the logic? Then you can use google to figure out how to do this in Java

Comment: You have an error in your pass() methode it should be if(mark >= 40) count++; but i guess it is just a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collections.max(people, yourComparator)` where `yourComparator` uses `getMark` as the comparison field: You could do:

```
Student maxStudent = Collections.max(people, new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student first, Student second) {
        if (first.getMark() > second.getMark())
            return 1;
        else if (first.getMark() < second.getMark())
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the top mark you create a variable which you replace each time a higher mark is found. If you are already looping you can find the average by summing all marks in a loop and divide it by total people. Here I have done both in the same loop:

```
int totalMark = 0;
int topMark = 0;
for (int i=0; i< people.size(); i++) {
    int mark = people.get(i).getMark(); 
    if (mark > topMark) {
        topMark = mark;
    }
    totalMark += mark;
}
int averageMark = totalMark / people.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by gathering statistics in the add(Student) method:

```
public class Course {
    private ArrayList<Student> people = new ArrayList<Student>();
    private int passing = 0;
    private int failing = 0;
    private int top = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int sum = 0;

    public void add( Student s ) {
        people.add( s );
        if(s.getMark() >= 40){
            passing++;
        }
        else {
            failing++;
        }
        sum += s.getMark();
        if(s.getMark() > top) {
            top = s.getMark();
        }
    }

    public int pass() {
        return passing;
    }

    public int fail() {
        return failing;
    }

    public int top() {
        return top;
    }

    public double average() {
        return sum / people.size();
    }
}
```

To answer your questions directly, top is simply found my comparing each mark to the maximum found mark.  Average is found by dividing the total sum by the number of marks.

Comment: Hello johncarl, that average is the average of the last input from a user, e.g the last input was 90 so it finds the average of that instead of all of them?

Comment: oops, missed a character (+=), sum should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `Comparable` interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) with your `Student` class and then to use `Collections` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class to use `max` and `min` functions to get the max and the min grade values. To get the average grade value you just have to iterate the `ArrayList` making the sum of the grade values and finally dividing the sum by the `ArrayList.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. It may help you.

[Java program to find average of all numbers except top three](http://msumca2012.blogspot.in/2013/07/java-a2p3-java-program-to-find-average.html)

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.